# oracle stored procedure error on large nvarchar2 value return

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, nvarchar

We have wrote an oracle function that returns nvarchar2 . it works fine when it return small value like 'hello'. However it return "ORA-06502 : character string buffer too small"  error when the nvarchar2 goes long (about 3000 character). is there a limit in the size of function's return value?

we use the function like this:

```
SELECT sampleFunction('sampleArg') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: There's a limit to the size of the variable in which the result of the function will be stored

Comment: Did you consider changing the function, so that it returns a `NCLOB`? This may or may not meet your needs - it depends on how you use the function values, for example you wouldn't be able to group or order by a `NCLOB`, but it would allow you virtually unlimited length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing function's return type from NVARCHAR2 to CLOB.

Answer (score 1):

The datatypes are [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6). For `NVARCHAR2` it says:

> Variable-length Unicode character string having maximum length *size* characters. You must specify size for `NVARCHAR2`. The number of bytes can be up to two times *size* for AL16UTF16 encoding and three times *size* for UTF8 encoding. Maximum *size* is determined by the national character set definition, with an upper limit of:
>
> - 32767 bytes if `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED`
> - 4000 bytes if `MAX_STRING_SIZE = STANDARD`
>
> Refer to Extended Data Types for more information on the `MAX_STRING_SIZE` initialization parameter.

So 3000 *characters* isn't a limit; but with multibyte characters you're reaching 4000 *bytes*. (Assuming you're on 12cR2 with standard string lengths, or any previous version).

That's the limit in a SQL context, which is what you have with the query you showed.

In a PL/SQL context [things are slightly different](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-9410B67C-0E65-45BE-9376-0BD97E39D678). The variable you define to select the function result *into* has to be big enough for the value being generated, and the sizing you give it may not be quite what you expect depending on your default [length semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/choosing-character-set.html#GUID-B3C74175-7F77-49A6-9CC9-1F6F70F3A69D). You can specify more explicitly with, say, either of these:

```
declare
  variable1 nvarchar2(4000 char);
  variable2 nvarchar2(4000 byte);
...
```

The difference between those really is that either of those variables could accept 4000 single-byte characters, but the first would also accept up to 4000 multibyte characters (up to the overall 32767 byte hard limit), whereas the second would still error with less that 4000 multibyte characters if the total number of *bytes* exceeds 4000.

You also need any variables defined *inside* your function to be large enough to hold the value you're returning - including any multibyte characters.